# Proof that $(L_{all})^C$ is not recursively enumerable

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

**The problem:**

We have the language $L_{all} = \{\operatorname{Kod}(M) | M \text{ is a turing machine and } L(M) = \Sigma ^*\}$

Hence, $L_{all}$ is the set of all encoded Turing machines (the $\operatorname{Kod}()$ is the encoding function) which accept all words as input.

One needs to show that $(L_{all})^C$, the complement of $L_{all}$ is not in $\mathcal{L}_{RE}$, that means it is not recursively enumerable.

By definition, in $(L_{all})^C$ we have all strings which do not represent correctly encoded Turing machines as well as encoded Turing machines which reject at least one word from the alphabet.

**What have I tried so far:**

- One idea was to use the diagonalization argument that can be used to prove that $L_{diag}$, the diagonal language is not recursively enumerable. This however doesn't seem to work.
- I tried to prove that the statement is wrong (i.e. $(L_{all})^C)$ is recursively enumerable: The proof would more or less go like this (not very formal): Let $A$ be a Turing machine deciding if $x \in  (L_{all})^C$. We first check if $A$'s input is a correctly encoded Turing machine ($x = \operatorname{Kod}(M)$), if not we reject. If it is, we associate every word from $\Sigma^*$ with a prime $p$ and then use this to simulate all words on $M$ at once, (in the $p^i$th step of $A$ we simulate the $i$th step of $M$ on the $p$th word). This is where my counter proof fails. Since there are uncountably infinitely many words in $\Sigma^*$ and only countably infinitely many primes. However I do not see a way how I can use this fact to prove the original statement.

Any suggestion or hints would be greatly appreciated since I am genuinely interested how one approaches such a proof.

**Full disclosure**
 This was a bonus question on an old exam (not connected to homework) and I am curious how one can prove this, especially since it seems to be somewhat counter intuitive.

Comment: Your language is known as TOT or TOTAL, and it is completely for the second level of the arithmetical hierarchy. In particular, it is neither r.e. nor co-r.e. If you just want to show the latter, reduce the halting problem to your language or its complement.

Comment: Isn't the halting problem recursively enumerable but not recursive, since if a Turing machine halts on some input one can find out in finite time (by simulating until it halts). How exactly would a reduction from the halting problem help if it's in a "stronger" category than the TOTAL language. (Sorry for asking ,I am a second undergrad and just getting started with complexity)

Comment: TOTAL is stronger than HALT. HALT is complete for the first level of the arithmetical hierarchy, while TOTAL is complete for the second level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let HALT be the following version of the halting problem: Given a Turing machine $T$, determine whether it halts on the empty input.

Here is a computable reduction from HALT to $L_{all}$: Given a Turing machine $T$, construct a Turing machine $T'$ which erases its input and then transfers control to $T$. You can check that $T \in \mathrm{HALT}$ iff $T' \in L_{all}$. This shows that $L_{all}$ cannot be co-r.e. Indeed, if $L_{all}$ were co-r.e. then HALT would be co-r.e. Since HALT is also known to be r.e., it would be recursive; but we know that HALT is not recursive.

Here is a computable reduction from HALT to the complement of $L_{all}$: Given a Turing machine $T$, construct a Turing machine $T'$ which on input $n$ runs $T$ on the empty input for $n$ steps; if $T$ halted, $T'$ enters an infinite loop, and otherwise $T'$ halts. You can check that $T \in \mathrm{HALT}$ iff $T' \notin L_{all}$. This shows that $L_{all}$ cannot be r.e. Indeed, if $L_{all}$ were r.e. then HALT would be co-r.e., and we get a contradiction like in the preceding paragraph.

In fact, $L_{all}$ is $\Pi_2$-complete; it is sometimes known as TOT or TOTAL. Thus $L_{all}$ is stronger than HALT, which is only $\Sigma_1$-complete.

Comment: I understand how this shows that $L_{halt} \leq L_{all}$ as well as $L_{halt} \leq (L_{all})^C$. In our textbook we have shown that $L_{halt}$ is recursively enumerable. So the two reduction are necessarily true if $L_{all} $ is not in r.e. but not sufficient, since by reducing the halting problem they could also be in r.e.. I don't quite understand how the not in r.e. part follows from this.

Comment: If $L_{halt}$ were co-r.e. then it would be recursive, but Turing proved that it isn't.

Comment: Yes but $L_{halt}$ is still r.e. and we are reducing $L_{halt}$ to $L_{all}$ which essentially just tells me that $L_{all}$ is not recursive. Similarly we can also only show that $(L{all})^C$ is not recursive by reducing $L_{halt}$ to $L_{all}^C$. Since we already know that $L_{all}$ is not recursively enumerable we cannot make any statement about $(L{all})^C$ (if it were recursively enumerable $(L{all})^C$ couldn't be recursively enumerable since otherwise both languages would be recursive). There is probably something in your reasoning that I don't understand yet.

Comment: I wrote out the argument in full.